# GRUB for Android taking too long to install

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, installation

I have this Digital2 10 inch Windows 8.1 tablet and I want to install Android Lollipop as the main operating system. So I properly load the android installer image to a usb, boot the tablet from usb, and it loads and even runs live just fine. The problem is that when I select install grub bootloader, it seems to hang on the screen. The confirmation window stays there, but a black bar with a blinking MS-DOS like cursor for more than 10 minutes. Is the installation of grub in this manor supposed to take this long, or should I try some other images?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I just needed to go into the bios and enable some kind of linux mode. That's something I didn't expect to find on a Windows tablet.